# What does the phrase "nec non" mean? (Metamorphoses I.612-614)

Tags: classical-latin, meaning, ovidius, metamorphoses, enclitic

In this passage from the Metamorphoses, Juno just descended from heaven onto earth to spy the whereabouts of her husband. Jupiter, having foreseen his wife's arrival, changes Io into a heifer.

> speciem Saturnia vaccae,
>   quamquam invita, probat nec non, et cuius et unde
>   quove sit armento, veri quasi nescia quaerit.
>   (Metamorphoses 1:612-614)

I'm having some trouble with this passage. Here's my best shot at a translation.

> Juno (Saturnia), although unwilling, approves the appearance of the cow, and asks  to whom, and from where, and to which herd it belongs, as if not knowing the truth.

Here are the details which stump me.

1. What on earth should I make of the phrase "nec non"? I kind of just glossed over that.
2. Is quove just quo with an enclitic -ve? Are -ve and -que equivalent?

I appreciate any feedback, including any other improvements I could make.

Comment: I don't know if the punctuation is your own, but it's misleading -- there's a clause break after *probat*, and *nec non* connects that clause with the following one (whose verb is *quaerit*): *speciam probat, nec non (=et) quaerit*.

Comment: @TKR Good point. I was using thelatinlibrary.com as my source. But I just checked Perseus and it punctuates the clause differently. It encloses "probat" in commas.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*[Necnon](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=ls&lang=la&word=necnon&filter=CUTF8)* can be written as two words, "and not not"; it has a positive meaning because of the double negative. It can be translated as *and* with an appropriate adverb, such as *and yet, and in fact*.

The enclitic *-ve* works just like *-que*, except that it means "or" rather than "and".

Comment: Thanks! One question. In my translation, it wouldn't make sense to translate "necnon" as "and yet" or "and in fact", since you would end up with: "Juno, although unwilling, and in fact approves the appearance of the cow..." How would you put the whole thing together?

Comment: @ktm5124: I think you've misread your own translation: *nec non* comes after *probat*. She approves and in fact inquires (if "in fact" is appropriate here).

Comment: Oh, thanks! That answers it.

Comment: One more minor point of confusion. As you see, I translated the enclitic -ve as "and" instead of "or". But given the fact that two et's precede the -ve, how would you translate the clause? Would it be: "and asks to whom, and from where or which herd it belongs"? Sounds a little awkward.

Comment: @ktm5124: The enclitic *-ve* is normally translated as "or", but, in questions and negations, the words "and" and "or" are often similar, so you can translate it as "and" if that fits the sentence.

Comment: See here under the first "2": http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=ls&lang=la&word=ve%231&filter=CUTF8

Comment: Thanks! That helps. I will probably translate it as "and" then.

Answer (score 0):

Neque (nec) non (also in one word, necnon), emphatically affirmative, *and also*, *and besides, and indeed, and*:

- Lewis and Short Dictionary

Comment: Welcome to the site! Many of your answers seem to have accumulated votes down and comments pointing out issues. If need any help figuring out what to do, consider asking a question on [our meta site](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/) and we can help you find the most productive ways to use this site. I hope you'll stick around and spend time learning Latin with the rest of us, and also remember to [vote up](https://latin.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) any posts you find useful.